# Unexpected Python behavior with dictionary and class

Tags: python

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.see=0
        self.dic={"1":self.see}

examine=test()
examine.see+=1
print examine.dic["1"]
print examine.see
```

this has as a result 0 and 1 and it makes no sense why.

```
    print id(examine.dic["1"])
    print id(examine.see)
```

they also have different memory addresses

However, if you use the same example but you have an array instead of variable in see. You get the expected output.

Any explanations?

This gives the expected output:

```
class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.see=[0]
        self.dic={"1":self.see}

examine=test()
examine.see[0]+=1
print examine.dic["1"][0]
print examine.see[0]
```

Comment: How to make it work then?

Comment: Based on your posted solution are you sure you don't just want a generator?

Comment: Why would you want to make it work? Accessing that integer through `self.see` is easier and faster than through `self.dic[1]` in any case. As you see you should not only explain the problem /you do that) but also explain why you are doing what you are doing. What is the aim of the code? That helps you get better answers.

Comment: You posted a solution but never explained what was the problem.

Comment: Solutions have no place inside a question, defeats the purpose. Answer it in the section below, by clicking "Answer Your Question".

Comment: @LennartRegebro I am somewhat using the dictionary structure as a parser. I need to do that as a reverse table.

Comment: @hus787 I don't have enough reputation

Comment: @hus787 I just got enough reputation to do that. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @user2789433 That's to vague for me to offer any improved solutions on it, especially since I don't see how your current solution helps you. (And if you register your email and pick a proper username you get a 100 points reputation for free. ;-) )

Comment: -1. This is not absurd, but well documented. Not everything one doesn't grasp, has to be absurd.

Comment: @Hyperboreus ["do not judge a book by its cover"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_judge_a_book_by_its_cover)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

Arrays/`list`s are mutable whereas integers/`int`s are not.

Comment: There are no arrays in Python.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid `import array`

Answer (score 3):

lists are mutable (they can be changed in place), when you change a list the same object gets updated (the id doesn't change, because a new object is not needed).

Integers are immuable - this means to change the value of something, you have to create a new object, which will have a different id. Strings work the same way and you would have had the same "problem" if you set `self.see = 'a'`, and then did `examine.see += ' b'`

```
>>> a = 'a'
>>> id(a)
3075861968L
>>> z = a
>>> id(z)
3075861968L
>>> a += ' b'
>>> id(a)
3075385776L
>>> id(z)
3075861968L
>>> z
'a'
>>> a
'a b'
```

In Python, names point to values; and values are managed by Python. The `id()` method returns a unique identifier of the *value* and not the *name*.

Any number of names can point to the same *value*. This means, you can have multiple names that are all linked to the same id.

When you first create your class object, the name `see` is pointing to the value of an integer object, and that object's value is `1`. Then, when you create your class `dic`, the `"1"` key is now pointing to the same object that `see` was pointing to; which is `1`.

Since `1` (an object of type integer) is immutable - whenever you update it, the original object is replaced and a new object is created - this is why the return value of `id()` changes.

Python is smart enough to know that there are some other names pointing to the "old" value, and so it keeps that around in memory.

However, now you have two objects; and the dictionary is still pointing to the "old" one, and `see` is now pointing to the new one.

When you use a list, Python doesn't need to create a new object because it can modify a list without destroying it; because lists are mutable. Now when you create a list and point two names to it, both the names are pointing to the same object. When you update this object (by adding a value, or deleting a value or changing its value) the same object is updated - and so everything pointing to it will get the "updated" value.

Answer (score 2):

`examine.dic["1"]` and `examine.see` do indeed have different locations, even if the former's initial value is copied from the latter.

With your case of using an array, you're not changing the value of `examine.see`: you're instead changing `examine.see[0]`, which is changing the content of the array it points to (which is *aliased* to `examine.dic["1"]`).

Comment: I understand... so how can I make it be used as a reference or pointer in the example above?

Comment: @user2789433: You can't, when `see` is a number, because you can't change the value of a number.  If you want the dict to "see" the changes in `see`, you need to make `see` some kind of mutable object and change its state.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `self.dic={"1":self.see}`, the dict value is set to the value of `self.see` at that moment.  When you later do `examine.see += 1`, you set `examine.see` to a new value.  This has no effect on the dict because the dict was set to the *value* of `self.see`; it does not know to "keep watching" the name `self.see` to see if is pointing to a different value.

If you set `self.see` to a list, and then do `examine.see += [1]`, you are not setting `examine.see` to a new value, but are changing the existing value.  This will be visible in the dict, because, again, the dict is set to the *value*, and that value can change.

The thing is that sometimes `a += b` sets `a` to a new value, and sometimes it changes the existing value.  Which one happens depends on the type of `a`; you need to know what `examine.see` is to know what `examine.see += something` does.

Answer (score 1):

Others have addressed the mutability/boxing question. What you seem to be asking for is *late binding*. This is possible, but a little counterintuitive and there's probably a better solution to your underlying problem… if we knew what it was.

```
class test:
  @property
  def dic(self):
    self._dic.update({'1': self.see})
    return self._dic
  def __init__(self):
    self.see = 0
    self._dic = {}

>>> ex=test()
>>> ex.see
0
>>> ex.see+=1
>>> ex.see
1
>>> ex.dic
{'1': 1}
>>> ex.see+=1
>>> ex.dic
{'1': 2}
```

In fact, in this contrived example it's even a little dangerous because returning `self._dic` the consumer could modify the dict directly. But that's OK, because you don't need to do this in real life. If you want the value of `self.see`, just get the value of `self.see`.

In fact, it looks like this is what you want:

```
class test:
  _see = 0
  @property
  def see(self):
    self._see+=1
    return self._see
```

or, you know, just `itertools.count()` :P

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me. Feel free to use it.

```
class integer:
    def __init__(self, integer):
        self.value=integer
    def plus(self):
        self.value=self.value+1
    def output(self):
        return self.value
```

The solution replaces the mutable type int with a class whose address is used as reference. 
Furthermore you can make changes to the class object and the changes apply to what the dictionary points. It is somewhat a pointer/datastructure.